# How to update a database with Ajax using switch toggle button?

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

Hi If I press the button I want the slider_durum to be 1. How do I do that?

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GdkQ.png)

My buttons:[switch toggle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSEdX.png)

code:slider.php

```
<td>
    <div class="custom-control custom-switch custom-switch-success custom-switch-glow custom-control-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id='<?php echo $row['slider_id']; ?>'  <?php echo $row['slider_durum']==1?'checked':'' ?>>          
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="<?php echo $row['slider_id']; ?>"></label>
    </div>
</td>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.custom-control-input').click(function (event) {
            var slider_id = $(this).attr("slider_id");  //take id value

            var slider_durum = ($(this).is(':checked')) ? '1' : '0';
            //We receive active or passive information according to the checkbox.

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'islem.php',  //my process page
                data: { slider_id:slider_id, slider_durum: slider_durum }, //post data
                error: function () {
                    alert('Hata');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is my islem.php(precess.php)

[islem.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAFBi.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will need to be a lot more specific about what you need to accomplish and where you are having problems with the code shown. Also tell us what is and what isn't working and all errors encountered. [ask]

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.